# How to manage workflow of maintaining 2 github repos that have only a slight difference in frontend?

Tags: git, github, workflow, monorepo

I am in a unique situation where I have to manage a project that has an online and offline version. Both this versions will use the similar frontends and the same backend but different ways of calling the apis and some different pages.

Can anyone suggest a workflow with git that will help me manage this? I need a way so that I can manage the 2 repos and keep them updated at the same time.

So if I update frontend of online only `repo 1` I can get a option to update offline `repo 2` if I want and vice versa.

Comment: Separate branches(a single local repo can hold both branches.. or more if you need to) and then push separate branches to different remotes (a single local repo can have more than one remote registered).

Comment: Not related to the original question but having 2 repos for your need feels a bit "overkill", maybe a modular approach in a single repo would fit better. Just a thought as we don't have all the details.

Comment: @eftshift0 that's a great idea hadn't thought of it. I have a couple of questions though: 

1. How would you handle updates to the different repos? Currently we are doing that through pull requests on the production branch and merge and push on the test branch. The test branch is reset to be same as production after all pull request has been  merged to production. 

2. I am assuming the local repo will have 2  branches each for production & test for the online and offline upstream repos. Are all this branches synced with both the remote repos or only the relevant ones?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is very similar to how you would handle a "fork" on any GitHub repo and keep it synced with the original repo.

For this reason, you might want to have a look to https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/quickstart/fork-a-repo#keep-your-fork-synced

The global picture is to have a single local repo with 2 remotes configured and merge/pull/push alternatively from/to these 2 remotes.